# VSCode intellisense not work when you click "Tab"

Tags: javascript-intellisense

Can someone help me with my problem?
HOW do I fix this EMMET VSCode so that when I write "log" and click " tab "I get" intellisense " and can select a variable?

On the video in the first version of the error, "intellisense" is missing. Then in the video, the second version of "intellisense" appears. I don't want to write every time to the manual console.log(), but if I press "Tab", "intellisense" doesn't appear automatically, I have to press CTRL + Space.

Don't ask me to manually press CTRL + Space every time, I want to know how to do everything automatically?

[Here is an example in the video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pqmq5lipcEQGwwsyqaoohjdjxdnIPCTD/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please try to clarify your question. It's difficult to understand as written.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pqmq5lipcEQGwwsyqaoohjdjxdnIPCTD/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I write `log` and press TAB I get `console.log(<text Focus is here>)` as a result.

If I immediately start writing the name of the variable `st..` then intellisense does not appear. The video clearly shows this.